# What do we call this diagram as?Do we call it as E-R diagram?

Tags: diagram, entity-relationship

Thanks a lot for your help. I really need to make it clear :(

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is an [Entity Relationship Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model), using Chen's notation.

The inclusion of field names muddies this a bit - an ERD shouldn't really express this information AFAIK.

Comment: thanks a lot for ur reply! so, how many types of notation do we have? we are allow to use any notation we like?

Comment: @Joey - No problem.  You can use any notation you like.  If others are to interpret your ERD though then best to use a standard notation rather than having to explain your own!  Take a look @ the Wikipedia article I linked to in my answer.

Comment: I have seen the explaination in wiki before I posted this question.I was quite confuse,that is why I posted this question here.Thanks a lot for making me clear! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a [UML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) diagram

Comment: hmmmmm? im not sure what is UML diagram. but i'll check it out. thanks anyway :)